# Read text file line by line in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, web

I have a text file and I would like to read it line by line and display them separately. For example, the first line of the text file is 'andy' and the second line contains 'male', I want to display it in html like :

Name: andy 
gender:male

So far I can only retrieve all the information, but I was unable to split them. Anyone can help me to solve this?

```
           <%
               String paths="somepath/hotel1.txt"; 


                File fileObject = new File(paths);

                char data[] = new char[(int) fileObject.length()];
                FileReader filereader = new FileReader(paths);

                int charsread = filereader.read(data);
                out.println(new String(data, 0 , charsread));

                filereader.close();
            %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BufferedReader and read line per line

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(paths));

String line1 = null, line2 = null;
line1 = br.readLine();
if (line1 != null) {
    line2 = br.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Using JSP scriplets - bad code practice. Use JSTL or another tag libs. Also you can write your own tags